# Can SharePoint 2013 apps run in SharePoint Foundation 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, 2013, sharepoint-addin

I apologize in advance if this is a silly question, but I'm new to SharePoint, don't fully understand the concept of SharePoint apps and was asked to investigate this.  I've been told that `SharePoint Foundation 2013` does not run SharePoint apps, but I can't find anything to verify this claim.

About six minutes into this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Uf4wvQ2we0 Yaroslav talks about rumours that the app infrastructure isn't supported on SharePoint Foundation.

Can SharePoint 2013 apps run in `SharePoint Foundation 2013`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can run SharePoint 2013 apps in SharePoint Foundation 2013, SharePoint Server 2013 Standard, and SharePoint Server 2013 Enterprise as well as future Office 365 support.

You can back this up by going to any MSDN page about SharePoint 2013 apps and looking at the text at the top of the article that says "Applies to:".

You could use [Install and manage apps for SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161232.aspx) or [Overview of apps for SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161230.aspx) or even [Configure an environment for apps for SharePoint (SharePoint 2013)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161236.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

As rjcup3 said you can run the apps in Sharepoint foundation 2013.

and also please check on how to [configure the app domain](http://www.sharepoint-journey.com/app-management-sharepoint-2013.html) for SharePoint server 2013.

and how to [develop the app in SharePoint server 2013 RTM](http://www.sharepoint-journey.com/app-development-in-sharepoint.html).

Answer (score 3):

Since yesterday the App support is also officially documented on Technet. 
[See yourself](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/jj819267.aspx#bkmk_FeaturesOnPremise)

Until yesterday all App relevant features were stated as "No".

[image: Statement on Technet before]

I created a ticket about it some time ago, because a lot of other articles about Apps on MSDN were saying that App development is working in SharePoint foundation.

**BUT there are limitations though**, because User Profile Service Application is not available. So a generic "Yes, apps work in foundation" is still not the full truth.

Answer (score 2):

Before answering your question I wish to share the differences between **Sharepoint Foundation** and **SharePoint server**.
**SharePoint Foundation** requires no licensing and is essentially free. There will be hardware, deployment, and other miscellaneous costs, but no licensing costs. That is a huge difference between it and Server.
Foundation provides basic site creation, document collaboration functionality just fine. And just that, is usually what organizations are looking for.

**SharePoint Server** adds various social, search, business intelligence, content management features to Foundation.

The apps for SharePoint provide a new method to deliver specific information or functionality to a SharePoint site. An app for SharePoint is a small, easy-to-use, stand-alone productivity app that solves a specific end-user need. Before you allow site owners to install apps in a SharePoint environment, you must plan how you want to support them. You have to determine your organization's policy around apps for SharePoint, plan your configuration settings, and determine how to manage and monitor the apps. This article discusses key decisions and helps you understand the choices to make as you plan to support apps for SharePoint.

For more Reference  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161237(v=office.15).aspx