# User Profile Service Application not available on central admin services

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin, user-profile-service, central-administration

I'm setting up an app store in sharepoint and the user profile service is required. The creation of this service is not available in the manage services on server. How can I enable this as on option on the new services tab?

Comment: What version of SharePoint? I suspect you have Foundation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can run SharePoint 2013 apps in SharePoint Foundation 2013, but with some limitation, as

> Some apps may be written to leverage client side code that will only work in SharePoint Server.  Those Apps won't work in Foundation.  For example, an app that interacts with the User Profile Service wouldn't work in Foundation since the User Profile Service doesn't exist in SharePoint Foundation.

More info for you:

Here's the [very detailed list of features for SharePoint](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/jj819267.aspx#bkmk_FeaturesOnPremise)

[Can SharePoint 2013 apps run in SharePoint Foundation 2013?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/56776/can-sharepoint-2013-apps-run-in-sharepoint-foundation-2013)

[Configure an environment for apps](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161236.aspx)

Comment: followed the article and it allowed certain apps to be used, many thanks

Answer (score 1):

User profile service is not available in the foundation version. You need to have SharePoint Standard or SharePoint Enterprise.

[SharePoint Server 2013 Features – Foundation vs Standard vs Enterprise](http://www.apps4rent.com/sharepoint-2013-features-comparison.html)

**Edit** I see now that Microsoft states that you can develop apps in SharePoint Foundation. However, i can't see how you can follow the article for setting up a development environment if User Profiles is required.

[SharePoint feature availability across on-premises solutions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/jj819267.aspx#bkmk_FeaturesOnPremise)

Comment: Oh, ive been following this msdn guide: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179923(v=office.15) It states that it 'Applies to: foundation 2013'. Seems slightly misleading. How would an app store be created on foundation?

Comment: You still need to have Standard or Enterprise edition to be able to this, sadly.

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/56776/can-sharepoint-2013-apps-run-in-sharepoint-foundation-2013

Comment: ok. I have read that you can install them through the app management service here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/59625/apps-for-sharepoint-foundation-2013. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can develop the apps in the SharePoint Foundation 2013 but with Limitation. Even MSFT mentioned all the below features avaiable in foundation but limitation. They put **1** with it.[image]

**1** Means: Certain app authoring features require user profiles, which aren’t available in SharePoint Foundation 2013.

**Conclusion** : Yes you can build the apps but not fully loaded.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/jj819267.aspx#bkmk_FeaturesOnPremise