# Sorry this app is not supported on your server

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin

I'm trying to install an Add-in (SP Hosted app) on SharePoint On Prem and I get below error message for both upgrade and install.

> "Sorry, this app is not supported on your server"

This add-in can be installed on others SP server and SP Online. There is a custom master page in add-in, no workflows. "SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure" feature is activated.

Do you have any idea why this happened?

Answer (score 1):

If you developing an app target to SharePoint online(you could view the settings by project property window), you can’t deploy to SharePoint 2013 directly.
[image]

You need either change the target SharePoint Version or update the app configuration by 7-zip tool.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Lee,
I checked the Target SharePoint version, its SP 2013 (v15.0.0.0). The previous version of the app can be installed (without custom master page), but the new version could not. Thats why I could not upgrade the app or install it on a new site.

Comment: Below are permission request:
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="Write" />
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/social/tenant" Right="Read" />
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/search" Right="QueryAsUserIgnoreAppPrincipal" />

Comment: Are your trying to install app from app store? If so, check 'Apps that require accessible internet facing endpoints enabled' or not in CA. In Central Administration, click Application Management.
On the Application Management page, click Manage Web applications.

On the Manage Web Applications page, select the web application that you want to change.
On the ribbon, click Manage Features.
In the feature list, next to Apps that require accessible internet facing endpoints, click Activate. similar thread here http://geekswithblogs.net/ThorvaldBoe/archive/2014/08/22/158459.aspx

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I activated the feature, but it does not work. I also created a new web application and then create a new site collection (Developer site) ==> Install the package via App In Tesing list ==> It works. So weird.
I got the issue on port 443

Answer (score 1):

I have been facing the same issue while installing a SharePoint App on my SharePoint 2013 Foundation Server. Looking for a resolution, I came across few blogs( [link 1](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/7db0eaea-881b-4ac0-878e-e0247d976f6f/sorry-this-app-is-not-supported-on-your-server-error-when-attempting-to-install-the-app-on?forum=appsforsharepoint), [link 2](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/655714d3-35cb-43fa-bdc7-c846d907af5d/error-attempting-to-installa-sharepoint-app-sorry-this-app-is-not-supported-on-your-server?forum=sharepointadmin), [link 3](http://blog.qumsieh.ca/2013/02/27/sharepoint-2013-sorry-this-app-is-not-supported-on-your-server/), [link 4](https://community.nintex.com/thread/9835)) which stated that the reason could be missing Workflow Manager.

But this didn't resolve my problem and I found that I was unable to install the app, because **User Profile Services wasn't configured** in my SharePoint environment.

Following is one of the [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/143659/user-profile-service-application-not-available-on-central-admin-services) to support my answer.